# vue/webpack doesn't inject css into the html

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-loader

I've been trying to get my custom webpack config to work. Production works great, but dev although I suppose it transpiles the CSS, doesn't include it in the document. This is my dev config, I don't think there's anything relevant in common and prod settings so I'll skip them.

I'm trying to also pipe it through postcss.

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // something here (I suppose)
          },
         // extractCSS: true
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
})
```

My postCSS config just in case:

```
module.exports = {
    "plugins": {
        "postcss-import": {},
        "postcss-url": {},
        "autoprefixer": {}
    }
}
```

My prod config extracts the CSS correctly - the only difference is basically `extractCSS: true` option in vue-loader's options (and extract CSS plugin obviously).

I suspect that I'm not injecting the file in any way, I've tried setting up custom loaders in vue-loader and I swear I've tried like every possible combination of `['vue-style-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'css-loader', 'style-loader']` but neither works. I was getting compilation errors or just a page without any styles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started to experiment whether files outside .vue files would load, so I added style and css loaders - this solved the issue. Even though I had had them installed, vue probably was relying on my rules to load it - not explicitly on 3rd party loaders. If someone wants to explain this behaviour more in-depth - feel free, I'm kind of curious what was going on and why templates such as `webpack` and `webpack simple` even though they don't have css loaders, it works and mine didn't.